# routes when nested resource and nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a Review model which is nested resource of Publication model. Review model have accept_nested_attributes_for review_comments. I wonder how could I show delete path to delete review_commment?

```
<% @review.review_comments.each do |review_comment| %>
   <%= link_to "delete", ???,  method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```

review.rb

```
has_many :review_comments, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :review_comments, :allow_destroy => :true
```

review_comment.rb

```
belongs_to :review
```

publication.rb

```
has_many :reviews
```

routes.rb

```
resources :publications do
  resources :reviews 
end

resources :review_comments
```

UPDATE

```
def create
 @review_comment = ReviewComment.new(params[:review_comment])
  if @review_comment.save
    redirect_to @review_comment, notice: 'Review comment was successfully created.'
   ....
end

def destroy
  @review_comment = ReviewComment.find(params[:id])
  @review_comment.destroy
  redirect_to :back, notice: "Deleted" 
end
```

UPDATE

```
 review_comments GET      /review_comments(.:format)                               review_comments#index
                       POST     /review_comments(.:format)                               review_comments#create
    new_review_comment GET      /review_comments/new(.:format)                           review_comments#new
   edit_review_comment GET      /review_comments/:id/edit(.:format)                      review_comments#edit
        review_comment GET      /review_comments/:id(.:format)                           review_comments#show
                       PUT      /review_comments/:id(.:format)                           review_comments#update
                       DELETE   /review_comments/:id(.:format)                           review_comments#destroy
```

Comment: do you have a review_comments controller.

Comment: I have, in this controller I have create and delete actions

Comment: can you paste the content of your review_comments_controller.rb file.

Comment: have u defined class name as: class ReviewCommentsController < ApplicationController in the first line.

Comment: then: <%= link_to "delete", review_comment_path(review_comment),  method: :delete %> should work. It will hit destroy action in ReviewCommentsController.

Comment: Unfortunately routting error uninitialized constant ReviewCommentsController

Comment: once paste complete file review_comments_controller.rb

Comment: I didn't get what do you mean in you last comment

Comment: U need to create app/controllers/review_comments_controller.rb and put there code from my post.

Comment: Follow @lol007 answer

Comment: I see my problem!!! My review_comments_controller.rb was named review_comments.rb. I have missed word controller, just so it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

For your routes:

```
<%= link_to "delete", review_comment,  method: :delete %>


class ReviewCommentsController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    @review_comment = ReviewComment.find(params[:id])
    @review_comment.destroy
    redirect_to review_comments_path # Or another path
  end
end
```

Comment: this was the first option I tried. doesn't work. routes error uninitialized constant ReviewCommentsController

Comment: U can define ReviewCommentsController and define `destroy` method there.

Comment: Update Model review_comment.rb and review_comments_controller.rb in your question, please

Comment: They are in my question. It's simple associations and in controller destroy and create actions. that's all.

Answer (score 0):

link_to with a method anything other than GET is actually a bad idea, as links can be right clicked and opened in a new tab/window, and because this just copies the url (and not the method) it will break for non-get links.

Also, links are clicked on by web page indexing spiders, and even though the links in question are probably only available to logged in users (and therefore not spiders) it's still bad practise.

It's better to use button_to instead, which makes rails generate a mini-form to produce the same result.

From a practical point of view buttons are better (for the above reasons) but they're also better from a conceptual point of view:  generally speaking, links should "take you somewhere", whereas buttons should "do something".  It's better to keep these two basic functionalities seperate.

Something like this,

```
button_to t('general.delete'), :review_comment_path(review_comment), :method => :delete, :confirm => t('review_comment.confirm_delete'), :title => t('review_comment.delete_question')
```